PnP.Core - how to authenticate using an app registration to get a PnPContext
Background
I'm trying to update existing logic that provides access to sharepoint doc library via PnPCoreSDKClient / pnpContexts.
All unit tests pass but now I need to connect live. So I'm adding / wanting to add logic to authenticate via an application registration (client id, client secret and tenantId)
Code:
using System;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Widgets.CopyFileClass
{

    public interface IPnPCoreSDKClient
    {
        Task<IPnPContext> GetPnPContextAsync(string siteUrl);
    }

    public class PnPCoreSDKClient : IPnPCoreSDKClient
    {
        private readonly IPnPContextFactory _contextFactory;
       
        public PnPCoreSDKClient(IPnPContextFactory contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public async Task<IPnPContext> GetPnPContextAsync(string siteUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                // Attempt to create a URI and fetch a PnPContext
                var uri = new Uri(siteUrl);
                return await _contextFactory.CreateAsync(uri);
            }
            catch (UriFormatException ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Provided site URL is not a valid URL.", ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("An error occurred while trying to obtain a PnPContext.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

What I've Tried
I found this article https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/api/PnP.Core.Auth.OAuthAuthenticationProvider.html
It seems to provide a TenantId and CLientId.  But no clientsecret.  So i'm guessing this isn't the right class to use.
Can someone just point me in the right direction?
Thank you!
